# FileInformation - extract file rename details

Tags: c++, winapi

What is the easiest and most efficient way to extract the file details from the "FileInformation" parameter, when the "FileInformationClass" is equal to "10" (i.e. file rename operation)?

I am trying to intercept an NtSetInformation API call and I'd like to modify the resultant file name.

At this point the only code I have is the definition for NtSetInformationFile, which is;

```
__kernel_entry NTSYSCALLAPI NTSTATUS NtSetInformationFile(
  HANDLE                 FileHandle,
  PIO_STATUS_BLOCK       IoStatusBlock,
  PVOID                  FileInformation,
  ULONG                  Length,
  FILE_INFORMATION_CLASS FileInformationClass
);
```

I searched the web and found an example where the FileInformation was changed to a "uint32_t" ([link](https://github.com/moyix/panda/blob/master/qemu/panda_plugins/win7proc/win7proc.cpp) - see line 794), but then the code, to get the file details, is rather extensive (Boost). Is there an efficient way to accomplish this task without using Boost?

Answer (score 1):

Why look at random code you find online when the structure you are asking about [is documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntifs/ns-ntifs-_file_rename_information)?

Like most of the NT API, file locations can be relative to a directory handle:

> If the file is not being moved to a different directory, or if the FileName member contains the full pathname, this member is NULL. Otherwise, it is a handle for the root directory under which the file will reside after it is renamed.

MSDN also tells you that there are 3 possible combinations:

> The file name string in the `FileName` member must be specified in one of the following forms.
>
> - A simple file name. (The `RootDirectory` member is NULL.) In this case, the file is simply renamed within the same directory. That is, the rename operation changes the name of the file but not its location.
> - A fully qualified file name. (The `RootDirectory` member is NULL.) In this case, the rename operation changes the name and location of the file.
> - A relative file name. In this case, the `RootDirectory` member contains a handle to the target directory for the rename operation. The file name itself must be a simple file name.

You probably need to use something like [`GetFinalPathNameByHandle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfinalpathnamebyhandlew) if you care about the full path. If you only care about the filename and not the path you can just parse the `FileName` member (the name part is after the last `\`).

To change the name you must call the real `NtSetInformationFile` function with your own `FILE_RENAME_INFORMATION` buffer.

Comment: Great, thank you for the information! After getting the filename using 'GetFinalPathNameByHandle', how do you change this name and then re-apply it back into the intercepted NtSetInformationFile function call?

Comment: I already told you, you have to allocate a new FILE_RENAME_INFORMATION struct (struct + space for your new filename), fill it with your replacement information and call the real function.

Comment: Do you have an example of how that is done? Sorry, I'm still learning! :)

Comment: Something like `PWSTR newpath = getnewpath(); SIZE_T cch = lstrlenW(newpath), totalsize = FIELD_OFFSET(FILE_RENAME_INFORMATION, FileName[cch+1]); FILE_RENAME_INFORMATION*pFRI = (FILE_RENAME_INFORMATION*) malloc(totalsize); lstrcpy(pFRI->FileName, newpath), pFRI->FileNameLength = cch * sizeof(WCHAR), pFRI->RootDirectory = 0, pFRI->ReplaceIfExists = 1; retval = NtSetInformationFile(..., pFRI, totalsize, ...);`

Comment: When I extract the FileInformation from NTSetInformationFile I don't see my renamed directory, when using the GetFinalPathNameByHandle you mentioned. When I run ProcMon I see the "renamed" directory listed under NTSetInformationFile. Is this data residing somewhere else?

Comment: GetFinalPathNameByHandle was just a suggestion for the incoming request so you could compare the full path. I don't know if the handle path is correctly updated after the rename but it should not matter in your case.

Comment: I also tried GetFileInformationByHandleEx, same thing, it shows the "original" filename and not the "renamed" directory/filename. Does anyone else know how you can uncover both the "original" as well as the "renamed" file?

Comment: I think reversing what you suggested (creating the File_Rename_Information and bringing it into the FileInformation parameter of NtSetInformationFile) might work. Might that work? Or is GetFinalPathNameByHandle doing this already?

Comment: No, you have to create your own buffer but you can use the same directory handle but your new filename needs to be part of a buffer you create.

Comment: Your sample took a new path and stuffed it into the NtSetInformationFile "FileInformation" parameter, but how do you do the inverse (take the FileInformation parameter and extract the existing path from it? From what I'm seeing, your suggested "GetFinalPathNameByHandle" approach doesn't work to extract the existing path from NtSetInformationFile.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196101/discussion-between-99boboster99-and-anders).